# Django messages not showing in template

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-messages

stuck with messages don't show up cant figure whats wrong with my code

```python
def studentreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Student has been created! You can view in the list!')
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = StudentRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'studentregister.html', {'form': form})
```

In the base template

```html
        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

When i save the student it doesn't show the message but when i view page source on chrome the message is there .help please.

```html
 </head>
        
        
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            Student has been created! You can view in the list!
        </div>
        
          
    <body>
```

Comment: It appears like you rendered the message between the `<head></head>` and `<body></body>`. Normally the browser does not render content in between the two. You should render messages in the `<body>`.

Comment: which part are you talking about

Comment: the `<div class="alert alert-success">
            Student has been created! You can view in the list!
        </div>` is rendered after the `</head>` and before the `<body>`. The `<head>` in HTML is not rendered, that contains data *about* the page (so meta-data), whereas the body is the actual page. But you here rendered it in the template between the two.

Comment: I have change still the message is not showing up

Comment: changed to *what*?

Comment: I have kept the message tag inside the body as you said